# How would you read these definitions?

Tags: c, object, pointers, constants

How should I read each of these definitions ?

1. `const char *arguments[]`
2. `char *const arguments[]`

I saw examples of `execl()` code using the first form but could not make it work under Linux and had to use the second form ?

Comment: Use [this](https://cdecl.org/) to figure out what such declarations mean.

Comment: @Blaze: According to that, `char *const arguments[]` means `Error error`.

Comment: It's also worth reading about [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: (1) gives me: declare arguments as array of pointer to const char
(2) gives me: declare arguments as array of const pointer to char.

Comment: @T.Decker And there you have the answer.

Comment: What do you mean with "could not make it work under Linux"? If you get an error message, please show it in your question and also show the code that produces the error. Function `execl()` doesn't take an array, but function `execv()` does and this is declared as `int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);`, so you have to use the 2nd form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C declarators are defined the following way

```
declarator:
    pointeropt direct-declarator
```

where the pointer is defined like

```
pointer:
    * type-qualifier-listopt
    * type-qualifier-listopt pointer
```

So this declaration

```
char *const arguments[]
```

can be rewritten like

```
char ( * const ( arguments[] ) )
```

So there is declared an array of unknown size of `constant pointers` to `char`.
That is you may not change the elements of the array because they are constant. But you may change the objects pointed to by the elements of the array because the pointed objects are not themselves constant.

Used as a parameter declaration this declaration is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to this declaration

```
char ( * const * arguments )
```

For example these two function declarations declare the same one function

```
void f( char ( * const ( arguments[] ) ) );
void f( char ( * const * arguments ) );
```

This declaration

```
const char *arguments[]
```

declares an array of unknown size of `non-constant pointers` to `const char`. 
That is you may change the elements of the array but you may not change the objects pointed to by the elements of the array beacuse the pointed objects themsekves are constant.

This declaration may be rewritten like

```
const char ( * ( arguments[] ) )
```

Or it is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
const char ( **  arguments )
```

These two function declarations

```
void f( const char ( * ( arguments[] ) ) );
void f( const char ( ** arguments ) );
```

declare the same one function.

Answer (score 2):

> const char *arguments[]

`arguments` is an array of unknown size of pointers to `const` qualified `char`.

> char *const arguments[]

`arguments` is an array of unknown size of `const` qualified pointers to `char`.